# Python Sockets - how can I get the IP Address of a Socket after I bind it to an IP

Tags: python, python-sockets

From the python library 'socket' is there a method that returns the IP of the socket that got binded to it?

Suppose a socket was declared and initialized like:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.connect(ip, port)
```

And I wanted to find the IP of a received datagram from a socket:

```
while True:
  for s in socks:
    recv = s.recv(1024)
    #get ip of s or socket
    #print received data from s.gethostname()
```

How would I go on about this?

Answer (score 1):

you can try with recvfrom this method returns data and the address of the sender

```
data, address = sock.recvfrom(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with [`socket.getpeername()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.getpeername).

Answer (score 0):

Simple way would be like

```
data, (ip, port) = sock.recvfrom(4096)
print (ip)
```